# JsonResult returns correct JSon but cannot create jtable in view c# mvc no error given

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable, jsonresult

This is my first time with JTable using mvc C#.
my JsonResult Action is returning correct JSon data but on my view it is not being converted to jtable and showing raw json data.

my code on view is as:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Individual Records Json";
}

<h2>Individual Matters</h2>

<div id="IndividualRecords"></div>

@section scripts{
     <!--Adding Theme for jTable Grid-->
    <!--You can choose any type of theme from the themes folder-->
    <link href="~/Scripts/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @*<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
    <link href="http://jtable.org/Content/themes/metroblue/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>

    <!--Adding jTable Plugin-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js"></script>

    <!--Adding our script file-->
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/Script.js"></script>*@  
}  


<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#IndividualRecordJson').jtable(
                                            {
                                            title: 'Individual Recordss',
                                            actions:
                                                {
                                                listAction: '/Dashboard/_IndividualRecord_Json',
                                                createAction: '/Dashboard/_IndividualRecord_Json',
                                                updateAction: '/Dashboard/_IndividualRecord_Json',
                                                deleteAction: '/Dashboard/_IndividualRecord_Json',
                                                },
                                            fields:
                                                {
                                                    RecordCode: {title: 'Record Code', width: '15%'},
                                                    RecordType: {title: 'Record Type', width: '15%'},
                                                    ClientName: {title: 'Client Name', width: '15%'},
                                                    Description: {title: 'Description', width: '15%'},
                                                    Cost: {title: 'Cost', width: '15%'}                                                    }
                                            }
                                        );
        $('#IndividualRecords').jtable('load');
    });



</script>
<body>
    <h2>This is a test line for nothing</h2>
    <div id="IndividualRecords">My data will come here.... some time...</div>
</body>
```

I also tried

```
 $('#IndividualRecords').jtable('load');
```

- I have removed script.js file and moved the code on page to check if it is the reason.
- Field names are changed for security reason. Field names are already in proper case.
- I am using [httpGet] in Action.
- I am using mvc version 4.0.3xxx

Comment: I need only listing so for testing purpose I added same action for all actions

Comment: Correction: I also tried      $('#IndividualRecords').jtable('reload');

Answer (score 0):

Try [HttpPost] instead. Looking at the examples on jtable.org, I don't see any HttpGet calls.

POST calls don't get cached, while GET calls do. I've seen a lot of APIs require POSTs instead of GETs for this reason.

Update: Also check your [network tab and select "XHR"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO8ly.png). There may be a failing web service call

Comment: If I use httpPost I get this error. 
Error: A public action method '_IndividualRecord_Json' was not found on controller 'myMVC.Controllers.IndividualRecordController'.

I am sure I need httpGet or dont mention. both return JSon data. 
My issue is, I get JSon data but cant load it into jTable. I am getting raw json data on page.

Comment: It looks like the values in the actions are actually API request calls then. What's the method name that you attached the [HttpGet] (or [HttpPost]) attribute to? You should replace the "listAction's" value with '/IndividualRecord/METHOD_NAME_HERE'

Answer (score 0):

removing [HttpGet] and left that blank solved my issue. Thanks anyways